# Edit a csv to show 5 columns in a specific order while applying a format to the datetime field

Tags: python, excel, csv, datetime

I have a 130 excel files all called cplt.csv each stored under two subfolders under the folder BM. i.e. BM/1/1/cplt.csv BM/2/2/cplt.csv and so on

I need to read each of these csv files and change it from 7 columns to 5 columns. The order in which I need the columns are 7th, 3rd, 2nd, 1st and 6th.

The 1st column is the datetime field which currently looks like 8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM
I need it to look like this -> 22-Aug-2015 01.19.01 or follow the ISO format ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").

I've got two problems the way I see it, 
1) I am currently unable to access all the cplt.csv files under my BM folder. 
2) I am not sure how to change the date time to the ISO format I need it to be and to output it back to the same csv file.

The code I've currently got is as follows:

```
import sys, argparse, csv, os

for file in os.listdir("BM"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
            for line in csvfile.readlines():
                array = line.split(',')
                newline = array[6] + "," + array[2] + "," + array[1] + "," + array[0] + "," + array[5]
```

Comment: Do you want to change the original file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yes please

Comment: I added the code that will do the changes I am just a little confused by your decsription of where the files are, *I have a 130 excel files all called cplt.csv each stored under two subfolders under the folder*, I cannot see the logic in that, `BM/1/1/cplt.csv` would be a subfolder under another subfolder, if you have arbitrary nesting then you need to os.walk BM

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Basically in the same directory as my project I have a folder called BM in which there are 130 folders. Each of these folders have another folder in which the csv file exists.

Comment: so there is `BM/folder/csvfile`?

Comment: BM/folder/folder/csvfile

Comment: Do the folders have a common name?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yes - for example - BM/folder1/folder1/cplt.csv - python3

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: Ok , I will edit in a sec

Comment: Ok, all done, it should so exactly what you want just cd to the directory BM and run the code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - thanks, so I cd to the directory where the BM folder and code_file exists and it doesn't work. Do I need to cd to inside the BM folder and move the code_file inside before running it?

Comment: No just cd to the folder that has the  BM folder and go from there, I have run the code with the exact same structure and it does exactly what it should

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So I'm doing a print(fle) in the for loop that iterates through the BM folder but nothing gets printed out. I'm in the folder which has both the BM folder and my alter_csv.py file

Comment: I added a sample of how I ran the program including the file structure, you can see the output yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each directory and run this function on each file, 
`datetime.strptime` will parse your dates and convert to `isoformat`, `itemgetter` pulls whatever columns you want to keep, we write to a tempfile using a `NamedTemporaryFile` and after after we have written the new content we replace the original file with `shutil.move`:

```
def change_file(in_file,cols):
    with open(in_file) as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        wr =  csv.writer(tmp)
        for row in r:
            new = [datetime.strptime(dt, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").isoformat() for dt in itemgetter(*cols)(row)]
            wr.writerow(new)
        move(tmp.name, in_file)
```

Now to find the csv files nested in the subdirectories we can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path
for fle in Path('./BM').glob('**/*.cplt.csv '):
    change_file(str(fle), (7, 3, 2, 1, 6))
```

using the same structure and a couple of test files:

```
In [41]: ls
BM/  test.py  

In [35]: ls BM
1/  2/

In [36]: ls BM/2/
2/

In [37]: ls BM/2/2/
file2.csv

In [38]: cat BM/2/2/file2.csv
8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM
8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM,8/22/2015 1:19:01 AM

In [39]: for fle in Path('./BM').glob('**/*.csv'):
            print(str(fle))
            change_file(str(fle), (7, 3, 2, 1, 6))
   ....:     
BM/2/2/file2.csv
BM/1/1/file1.csv

In [40]: cat BM/2/2/file2.csv
2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01
2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01,2015-08-22T01:19:01
```